# Python. Please help me with adding and maximum and minumum

Tags: python

In Python, you can repeat code 5 times by inserting 
the line →  for count in range (0,5): 
The code that follows this must then be indented.
Write a program to enter a class of percentage 
scores, assigning grades to each: 0-20,E…81-100,A
Print how many there were of each grade, the 
average score, and the highest and lowest scores.

```
A=0
B=0
C=0
D=0
E=0
for count in range(0,5):
    score = int(input("Type your class students' score."))
    if score >81:
        print("A")
        A=A+1
    elif score>61:
        print("B")
        B=B+1 
    elif score>41:
        print("C")
        C=C+1
    elif score>21:
        print("D")
        D=D+1
    else:
        print("E")
        E=E+1
print "There are",A,"number of A"
print "There are",B,"number of B"
print "There are",C,"number of C"
print "There are",D,"number of D"
print "There are",E,"number of E"
totalscore = sum(score)
highestscore = max(score)
lowestscore = min(score)
print "Average score is",totalscore/5
print "The highest score is",highestscore
print "The lowest score is",lowestscore
```

I have done it but it doesn't work from totalscore = sum(score).
I don't know how to get the average score and the maximum and minimum score.
Please help.

Comment: Do you notice that `score` is simply the last entered number? It doesn't make sense to do those calculations on a single number. Hint: you'll need to add each new `score` to something like a `list`. Then you can do those calculations on that `list`.

Comment: sorry but where and what do need to type to make the list.

Comment: That will certainly be in your textbook or other course materials.

Comment: Either for each iteration you check to update the min, max and total score or as @TigerhawkT3 said use a list to save all the scores entered

Comment: can someone please tell me how to create a list. I don't have any basic knowledge in python....

Comment: I'm sorry, it sounded like this was an assignment in a Python course. If you don't have any basic knowledge in Python, you should search for tutorials (like the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html)) and read a few lessons.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
from collections import Counter

grade_counter = Counter()
sum_score, highest_score, lowest_score = 0, 0, sys.maxint
TIMES = 5


class RangeDict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for k in self.keys():
            if k[0] < key <= k[1]:
                return super(RangeDict, self).__getitem__(k)
        raise KeyError

grade_range = RangeDict({
    (81, 100): "A",
    (61, 81): "B",
    (41, 61): "C",
    (0, 41): "E"
})

for i in range(TIMES):
    score = int(raw_input("Type your class students' score."))
    grade = grade_range[score]
    print grade
    grade_counter[grade] += 1
    sum_score += score
    if score > highest_score:
        highest_score = score
    if score < lowest_score:
        lowest_score = score


for grade in sorted(grade_counter):
    print "There are  %s number of A %d" % (
        grade, grade_counter[grade])

print "Average score is", sum_score / TIMES
print "The highest score is", highest_score
print "The lowest score is", lowest_score
```

First, I think you can use collections.Counter to record the grade counts. Then, the sum score, highest score and lowest score can be getted in the for block. : )

Answer (score -1):

You can create and fill a list with:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(10):
   my_list.append(i)
```

Comment: No my code does work. It creates a list with the values from 0 to 10. You can verify it by using `print my_list`. If your code does not work with a list you should be more specific on your answer.

Comment: it comes out with really strange answer

Comment: Then you should show how you implemented in your code. I can't guess how exactly you have implemented it. Just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help the discussion.

Comment: actually i don't know where to put that code. do i just put that code exactly same into my code?

Comment: print "There are",E,"number of E"
my_list = []
for i in range(10):
   my_list.append(i)
totalscore = sum(my_list)
highestscore = max(my_list)
lowestscore = min(my_list)
print "Average score is",totalscore/5
print "The highest score is",highestscore
print "The lowest score is",lowestscore 

when i do that it comes out like

Comment: Type your class students' score.90
A
Type your class students' score.53
C
Type your class students' score.65
B
Type your class students' score.86
A
Type your class students' score.90
A
There are 3 number of A
There are 1 number of B
There are 1 number of C
There are 0 number of D
There are 0 number of E
Average score is 9
The highest score is 9
The lowest score is 0

Comment: Well my code was just an example of how you can generate a list and fill it with values. You still have to adapt it to your problem, e.g. fill the array not with the values from 0 to 10 but with your scores.

Comment: so do I use

my_list = []
for i in range(score):
   my_list.append(i)

this?

but it doesn't work.. sorry

Comment: It doesn't create a list with values from 0 to 10 but from 0 to 9.  Also such a list is already created by `range(10)` so you are creating an empty list, then a list with values 0 to 9, then copy those values one by one into the empty list, just to throw away the list created by `range(10)` and keeping the now equal list you created first.  `my_list = range(10)` would have been less hassle. But those values are not needed anywhere.  A list with zeroes would have been more helpful: `my_list = [0] * 10`.

Comment: I didn't want to show how to create a list from 0 to 9 but to show how Jina how a list can be created and filled with values, so Jina could use it in his/her program.